# How do I point to the right place?

Tags: c, pointers

Edit: This is a part of a memory handing library, the purpose is to "reinvent" malloc.

I have a problem with the pointers in this code. I want to access the ch->size outside the function someFunc. The value of ch->size should be 1048576 (1Mb) but it is instead 4196464, my guess is that I do not point to the right place when casting to the Chunk again. How to do it right?

```
type *someFunc() {
    unsigned int size = 1048576;
    int totsiz = size;
    char *memory = (char*) malloc(size); 
    while (totsiz) memory[--totsiz] = 0; 

    header *head = (header *) memory;

    head->data = NULL;

    head->fr = (char *) (memory+sizeof(header)+sizeof(man));

    head->fn = (man *) (memory+sizeof(header));
    head->fn->firstFN = firstFN;
    head->fn->secondFN = secondFN;

    Chunk ch = (Chunk) memory+sizeof(header)+sizeof(man);
    ch->start = memory+sizeof(header)+sizeof(man)+sizeof(chunk);
    ch->size = size;
    ch->next = NULL;
    ch->name = 1;

    printf("%u", ch->size); // Print 1048576

    return (type *)(head->fn);
}
```

And then I call it like this:

```
type * imem = (type *) someFunc();

Chunk mem = (Chunk)((void *)imem-sizeof(char *));
printf("%d", mem->size); // Print 4196464
```

Chunk:

```
typedef struct _chunk chunk;
typedef chunk *Chunk;
struct _chunk {
  void* start;
  unsigned size;
  Chunk next;
  bool name;
};
```

Comment: provide complete example - e.g. the definition of `Chunk`.

Comment: You are collecting "head->fn - sizeof(char*)" in "Chunk mem". And obviously the structure of "head->fn" is different than Chunk. So you are trying to print some value from "head->fn" as "Chunk mem->size".

Comment: The compiler would have found the errors if you had not used any casts.

Comment: Are you sure that sizeof(man) = sizeof(char*) ???

Comment: Why don't you try returning "head" without any subtraction on "imem" and then make Chunk mem = head->fr ? Try to print the "mem->size" then.

Comment: I would like to do that, but I have to return head->fn. I then want to use the return value, and step back in memory (to head->fr, that would be one (char *) step back, right?) and then I would like to access head->fr (And the purpose is that the head->fr is pointing to Chunk ch).

Comment: How would you say that it is one char* back? That depends on the sizeof(man).

Comment: Oh, so it should be one sizeof(man) step back instead?

Comment: It should not be back. The address of "Chunk ch" should be ahead of the address of "head->fn". And also, "head->fn" is pointing to just the starting address, so I think you have to go a lot further. Again, the pointer arithmetic, increments by the num of bytes of the size of type it is pointing to. So, incrementing the pointer by 4 means you are going to jump over sizeof(header->fn) bytes 4 times.

Comment: But the address of Chunk ch is supposed to be stored in head->fr and therefore, I would go one (char *) step back to achieve the adress, or am I wrong here? I would then use this adress to find Chunk ch. There may be something wrong with the pointer at head->fr, I am not really sure.

Comment: What do you deduce from these:: "head->fn = (man *) (memory+sizeof(header));" and "Chunk ch = (Chunk) memory+sizeof(header)+sizeof(man);" ?

Comment: What do you think, the value of address pointed by "ch" is greater or lesser than "head-fn" ?

Comment: Ending this discussion, I would say, redesign your code and design. Try different concept to make your code readable and easy to debug. That would help you a lot. This code exposes a lot of bugs and may be future crashes. You don't want your reinvented malloc to do that.

Comment: head->fn = (man *) (memory+sizeof(header)); should "allocate" memory for the fn-struct (which is man). And the Chunk ch = (Chunk) memory+sizeof(header)+sizeof(man); should "allocate" memory for the Chunk ch.

Answer (score 0):

These three pointers:

```
head->fr = (char *) (memory+sizeof(header)+sizeof(man));
head->fn = (man *) (memory+sizeof(header));
Chunk ch = (Chunk) memory+sizeof(header)+sizeof(man);
```

all point to different locations in memory. When the function returns `(type *)(head->fn)`, and then the calling code subtracts `sizeof(char *)` from that (I don't know why), the `mem` value points to some location completely different from what you set to `ch` inside the function.

All of the pointer arithmetic here makes it very hard to follow what's going on. My recommendation is to abandon trying to do your own memory management within the `memory` array, and instead allocate each object its own storage with `malloc` the way God and Dennis intended you to.

Edit: knowing that this is an exercise to reimplement `malloc`, it's a little more understandable. I'm still not sure that all the pointer arithmetic makes sense and would probably recommend that you cast the `memory` buffer to a single pointer which encapsulates all of your header fields, something like:

```
struct _MemoryPiece {
    header mp_head;
    man mp_man;
    chunk ch;
}
typedef struct _MemoryPiece MemoryPiece;

type *someFunc() {
    MemoryPiece *mp = (MemoryPiece *) malloc(size);
    mp->mp_head.data = NULL;
    mp->ch.size = size;
    ...
    return mp;
}

MemoryPiece *mem = (MemoryPiece *) someFunc();
printf("%d", mem->ch.size);
```

Implementing a memory management library is going to involve some tricky pointer arithmetic no matter what, but by being careful about the types you use to keep track of allocated memory, you can at least minimize the problem.

Comment: The purpose is to reinvent malloc, as an exercise, so I cannot follow your recommendation here.

Comment: I would just use malloc once, and then run my own implementation of malloc in the big virtual memory that I allocated with malloc.

Comment: Well, that does make a little more sense. I've updated my answer with some more suggestions.

Comment: @Abhineet The OP's question was "how to do it right?" so I am offering a suggestion for how I would try to solve this problem "right." Feel free to downvote if you think I am so far off that I am solving the wrong problem :-)

Comment: No buddy, I didn't mean to downvote you. I know you are trying to help and the solution you are providing is good. :-)